# Tomcat instance fails to start: ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use

Tags: tomcat6, startup, jdwp

I have two tomcat instances with shared tomcat installation on a ubuntu box. 
Each server has its own shutdown port and own listener port.

When i start the second server (either one) I get the following error:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): 
No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: 
JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

I am not trying to run these servers in debug mode. Have no additional startup options supplied.

I have checked other threads here but none of the solutions work for me. I've done netstat on the concerned port and there is nothing.

Comment: have you made this entry anywhere while starting up, -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=3001,suspend=n if so, you can change the address to someother value as that is the one which is occupied -